# How can I populate a field based on another field only on the page load? (Infopath)

Tags: infopath

I'm creating an Infopath form, and what I'm trying to do is populate an extra textbox with the inital value of the field ONLY while loading.

I know that sounds weird, an example might be better:
-Field 1 starts blank, user changes the field to "100" and saves it. Extra_Field stays blank.
-When the form opened again, Extra_Field now populates with "100" and user changes Field 1 to "200", Extra_Field stays at "100", saves the form
-The field is opened again, Extra_Field now populates "200"...

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just go to the **extras menu → form options → open and save  → rules button**
and add a rule here. (These rules will only be perfomed once, during each opening.)

Mind to create your fields before.